# Are certain videos blocked by Youtube on the iPhone or is this a technical issue?

Tags: iphone, youtube

When I search for any major label band on my iPhone 4 almost none of the official video clips are available.

I can always find the equivalent clip on DailyMotion.

I used to be able to find more results on the "classic" version of Youtube, but Youtube now always redirects to the mobile version. This started sometime in the past couple of months.

Say for example any of MGMTs official or VEVO videos or Pumped Up Kicks by Foster the People. These can all be found and watched on a desktop browser, but can't be found anywhere on my iPhone.

Is there some licensing issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syndication setting that you choose when you upload a video to youtube in the video settings page under Broadcasting and Sharing Options that allows it to be played on mobile devices or not.

[image: Broadcasting and Sharing Options]

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, however it seems to be a blanket banning by major record labels, not a setting on individual videos.

Comment: I would have thought that was apparent from reading the text in the image I posted. Here is googles official support documentation for this question http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=184706

Comment: I think the link you provided points to more reasons. It does mention copyright and also not being available in certain countries. I think both of these cases is more likely e.g. We can't get Hulu in Australia.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing for certain I imagine it's because they want you to watch them on your computer, in Flash, so they can add in the advertising. Used to be you could disable Flash and Youtube would redirect to a HTML5 viewer but they've cut it down to the very bare minimum, so it doesn't seem like much of a leap for them to do it on mobile devices.